# Moved to 64-bit Win7 desktop, using 32 bit SSMS, certain XML fields not coming back consistently

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssms

Just got moved to a new Win7 64-bit desktop. I'm running the 32 bit version of SQL Server Management studio against a SQL Server 2005 DB server (not my choice, that's what was installed).

If I query the top 10 rows of a certain table one of whose fields is XML, about 50-90% of the records that come back don't appear to have their XML fields populated.

It gets weirder - some XML fields do not pose this problem at all. I suspect it has something to do with the length of the data in the field. I've played with the "XML Data" sizes in Tools => Options but it didn't fix the problem.

This was not a problem with Management Studio on my WinXP 32-bit desktop.

Has anyone else seen this? Anyone know of a solution/patch? Would running the 64 bit version of SSMS solve the problem?

Comment: Well, my work's infrastructure team found the solution - SSMS 2012 64 bit. Works like a charm and I think there is a performance improvement over whatever I had before (probably SSMS 2005).